# Totally real submanifold of 2 dimensional complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, complex-geometry

Let $X$  be a 2-dimensional complex  manifold and let $Y$ be a smooth submanifold of $X$ of two real dimension. Let $J$ be the complex structure on the tangent space $T_xX$. The submanifold $Y$ is called totally real if $T_xY\cap J(T_xX)=\{0\}$ for all $x\in Y$.

Among the following submanifolds $Y$: $S^2$, $S^1\times S^1$ and $\mathbb RP^2$, which one can be embedded in $X$ as a totally real submanifold. Why $\mathbb RP^2$ can't be one of them?

Comment: $\Bbb{RP}^2 \subset \Bbb{CP}^2$ is totally real. Something is missing in your assumptions.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit it now

Comment: The affine quadric is symplectomorphic to the cotangent bundle of $S^{2}$ (see section 2.1 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.4146.pdf), so there is a lagrangian sphere by the Weinstein N-hood theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on $X$, but all $3$ of those surfaces can be embedded as totally real submanifolds in *some* complex manifold of dimension $2$.

In all cases we can use the fact that for a lagrangian submanifold in a Kähler manifold is totally real (which is proven in the answer to this question [What is the relation between totally real submanifold and Lagrangian submanifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2770284/what-is-the-relation-between-totally-real-submanifold-and-lagrangian-submanifold/2770343)).

1. $S^{1} \times S^{1}$ is Lagrangian in $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$ since it is a toric manifold, and the pre-image of a regular value of the toric moment map is a lagrangian torus.
2. $\mathbb{RP}^{2}$ is a lagrangian in $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$, embedded by just taking points whose homogeneous co-ords are real numbers.
3. To see $S^{2}$ as a lagrangain, just take a smooth rational curve with self-intersection $-2$ in a del Pezzo surface, which can be achieved by blowing up a point and then a point on its strict transform.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that $X$ is either $SL_2(\mathbb C)/\mathbb C^*$ the affine quadric or $\mathbb CP^1\times\mathbb C P^1$. Can the real projective space be embedded in $X$ in those cases?

Comment: @AmratA Note that the affine quadric is an *open subset* of $\Bbb{CP}^1 \times \Bbb{CP}^1$, not the whole thing. Once you specify $X$ this becomes harder to answer.

Comment: @Nick L, I see now the relation between Lagrangian submanifolds and totally real submanifolds. Does 3. in your answer  show that $S^2$ is a Lagrangian submanifold of $\mathbb CP^2$?!

Comment: @AmratA No, it shows $S^2$ as a Lagrangian submanifold of something much more complicated. I do not think it is true that $S^2$ may be embedded as a Lagrangian submanifold of $\Bbb{CP}^2$, but I am not well-versed in symplectic geometry, so I will let someone more expert confirm.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I have asked this in a separate question.