# The sphere $S^2$ is not a totally real submanifold of $\mathbb CP^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

So as the title says; Why the sphere $S^2$ can't be embedded as a totally real submanifod of $\mathbb CP^2$? I asked a similar question about totally real submanifolds. e.g see [Totally real submanifold of 2 dimensional complex manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004104/totally-real-submanifold-of-2-dimensional-complex-manifold/3004115#3004115)

Number 3 of the answer mentions the proof of $S^2$ being Lagrangian. But if $S^2$ is Lagrangian in $\mathbb CP^2$ then it follows that $S^2$ is  a totally real submanifold! Is it actually?